# How to get the sum of the numbers in multidimensional array with a condtion of numbers having less than 12 zeros between them

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, sum

I have imported Hourly rainfall data (25X366, big data) from excel to python as dataframe using pandas and converted it to array to get the sum of the numbers that have less than 12 zeros between them

so for example:

00000000000010300050304000000000000678

I would first add 1,3,5,3,and 4 from this data and then 6,7,8 separately because they come after 12 zeros.
Now I know how to make sums for each row of array but not sure how to add in the 12 zeros condition and make the numbers continue to add each other outside of their own row.

```
df = pd.read_excel("2010.xlsx")
df2 = df.to_numpy()
def sum(row):
    total = 0
    for num in row:
        total += (num)
    return total
a = (np.appy_along_axis(sum, 1, df2))
```

Additionally, I'm having issues with the dates of rainfall because they are written in normal numbers in excel and python keeps adding dates to the data when I use sum function

for example:

20220506 0000000010002030

and writing sum function for this row would give 20220512
How can I get this to work?

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.